# AutoHotKey, Updating Icons

Tags: icons, autohotkey

So i have a problem with updating the icon for my gui.
I want to have it so when i press a button the icon changes, and when i press another button it changes to a different icon.

I can change the icon once when i create the gui with this script:

```
gui, show, w0 h0
Menu, Tray, Icon, %A_WorkingDir%\Files\Red_Icon.ico, 1, 1
gui, destroy
```

But i cant seem to be able to change it multiple times

So im wondering how i change the icon multiple times/How to uppdate to icon

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to toggle between the icon one and icon two you can use this:

```
Gui, Add, Button, gNewIcon, Click to change icon
Gui, Show, w200 h200
Menu, Tray, Icon, C:\icon1.png, ,  ;first icon path
return

NewIcon:
if (toggle := !toggle)
  Menu,Tray,Icon, C:\icon2.png, ,  ;second icon path
else
  Menu, Tray, Icon, C:\icon1.png, ,  ;first icon path
return
```

If you want to switch between multiple icons then use this:

```
Gui, Add, Button, x10 y20 gNewIcon1, Click to change to icon 1
Gui, Add, Button, x10 y60 gNewIcon2, Click to change to icon 2
Gui, Add, Button, x10 y100 gIconDef, Click to change icon back to default
Gui, Show, w200 h200
Menu, Tray, Icon, C:\icon1.png, ,  ;first icon path
return

IconDef:
Menu, Tray, Icon, C:\icon1.png, ,  ;first icon path
return

NewIcon1:
Menu, Tray, Icon, C:\icon2.png, ,  ;second icon path
return

NewIcon2:
Menu, Tray, Icon, C:\icon3.png, ,  ;third icon path
return
```

Comment: This works perfectly except for one issue, this does not change the icon on the window and the taskbar icons. I assumed tray icons always were the same as window and taskbar icon but that does not seem to be the case.  So, Is there a way to also change the taskbar/window icon aswell as the tray icon?